# How to assign elastic ip to existing AWS application load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, devops

I have existing application load balancer.
I've prepared subnets, NAT with elastic ip.

My question is: is there any way to attach elastic ip (subnet) to existing application load balancer without recreating it/creating new network load balancer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In alternatively, you can use the Global Accelerator with the Target is your ALB.

Doing that way, you can have a static IP for your ALB.

Comment: Oh yes. You are right. Forgot about that. This could could be good solution to the question:-)

Comment: Thanks, sounds pretty good. However, I've already resolved it by creating lambda as a proxy

Comment: Hi Dom, with doing that way, the cost is depend on the traffics to your application and if it's large, it will be very expensive. Saying that Lambda is always a solution but not the best, you should consider it :-D

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there is no such possibility (except Ash'es answer). If you don't want to use NLB (only NLB provides static IPs) as you wrote in the question.

When you work with ALB, you should use its **DNS name**. If you require static IP, then ALB is not suited for your use case.

However, if you provide more information on what you are trying to achieve, some alternative ways could be possibly proposed.

Comment: @Dom Can you check Ash's answer? It could be good solution.